# Get x and y values from string: 'matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1)'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a function that returns x or y translate position of an element based on what `pos` was specified `'x'` or `'y'` like this

```
function getTranslate(el, pos) {
    var translate = '',
        position = 0;

    if(el.css('transform')) {
        translate = el.css('transform');
    }
    else if(el.css('-webkit-transform')) {
        translate = el.css('-webkit-transform');
    } else {
        translate = 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)';
    }

    if(pos == 'x') {
        position = /* Get x position here */ ;
    }
    else if(pos == 'y') {
        position = /* Get y position here */ ;
    }
}
```

When we grab transform property a string like `'matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1)'` ([more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#translate3d())) is returned for `translate3d(3px, 3px, 0)`. this gets stored in translate variable that I need to parse in order to get `position` variable to just store number value of either x or y position based on what was given to the function. I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse that string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can parse the translate string with regular expressions:

```
var regex = /translate3d\(\s*([^ ,]+)\s*,\s*([^ ,]+)\s*,\s*([^ )]+)\s*\)/;
var test = "translate3d( 10px,20px , 30px)"
var result = test.split(regex);
alert('x is '+result[1]+",  and y is "+result[2]);
```

Comment: I just realised it returns string like this 'matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1)' instead of what I mentioned before, my mistake, updated my question to why this string is returned

Comment: question - this returns an array of 5 values, where the first [0] and last [4] are just empty strings. How would you modify the regex to exclude those values?

Comment: Well, you could do  `test.match(regex)`  or `regex.exec(test)`,  which would both give you a 4 value array  (the first item being the entire matched text, the other 3 are the capture groups).  I don't think there is a way to modify the regex to get just the 3 values,  but you could always call `slice` on the result,  eg.  `test.match(regex).slice(1,4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of an element with .offset() or .position().

They are different one get position relative to the document and second relative to the offset parent.

```
position = element.offset();
position = element.position();
```

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

https://api.jquery.com/position/